# Set element height to end at start of specified element with CSS or jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way in jquery to dynamically set the height of an pseudo element based on the position of the top of another overlapping element.

For example lets say I have a header and a second element that are overlapping (this cannot be altered). Can you set the bottom of the header:after to end where the 2nd elements top starts for a seamless background using transparency. Any overlapping will obviously be darker in color.

In the example below header would have a height of 80px but it's pseudo element would stretch down only until it meets the top of element2, say at 40px (but this changes at diff screen sizes). The result would be the entire background of header and element2 are the same color.

CSS Example

```
 .site-header {
    background-color:  transparent; 
    width: 100%;
    height:80px;    
}

.site-header:after {
    background:rgba(251,75,4,0.6);
    width: 100%;    
    z-index-1;
}

.element2{
    height:500px;
    background:rgba(251,75,4,0.6);
    width:100%
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
OVERLAPPING
<element2>
```

The goal is seamless color from the top of the header to the start of element2, no overlap. If it wasn't for the pseudo element it would be easy but I'm trying to manipulate a plugin and I have no control over the html, hence the pseudo element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using `::after`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

header {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  height: 500px;
  background: rgba(251, 75, 4, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: green solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<header>
  lipsum
</header>
<div>
  test
</div>
```